# How to express.logger() all requests except GET /favicon.ico? (Nodejs/expressjs)

Tags: node.js, express

I want to log all requests except for those of favicon.ico.
At first I thought to simply create a function and call express.logger(), but calling express.logger() inside a function does not work.

```
//DOES NOT LOG
app.use("/", function(req, res, next){
    console.log('executing 1');
    express.logger();
    next();
});
```

It follows that I cannot use if statements to check res.url.

Now I'm trying the following but I am stuck:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url=="/favicon.ico"){
        //Somehow skip the next app.use
    }else{
        next(); //otherwise just go to next
    }
});

app.use("/", express.logger());
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

express.logger() function returns another function which has the signature of express middleware (function(req, res, next)). Calling it will not do the logging but just return the logger middleware.

Try this -

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url=="/favicon.ico"){
        next();
    }else{
        express.logger()(req, res, next);
    }
});
```

Remove app.use(express.logger()) from your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`express.favicon`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/favicon.html) middleware, and include that before you include the logger middleware. That's actually a use case mentioned on the `connect.favicon` (on which `express.favicon` is based) page:

```
app.use(express.favicon()); // you can also pass path to favicon file, see docs
app.use(express.logger());
```

([docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/favicon.html))